# How to convert (day month year) to ( month day year)

Tags: emacs, elisp

My e-mails in Wanderlust have a header that looks like this:

```
Date:  Wed, 23 Oct 2013 12:18:15 -0700
```

I would like to modify the beginning of my `print-to-pdf` function so that it searches the current buffer for the first date it finds (usually the first line of the buffer) and converts it into a proposed `pdf-file-name` that looks like this:

```
10_23_2013.pdf
```

The beginning of my `print-to-pdf` function looks like this:

```
(defun print-to-pdf (pdf-file-name)
  "Print the current buffer to the given file."
  (interactive (list
    (ns-read-file-name "Write PDF file: " "/Users/HOME/.0.data/" nil ".pdf")))
  (cond (
    (not (equal pdf-file-name nil))

  ***
```

Can anyone think of a way to search for the date and turn it into a proposed `pdf-file-name`?

---

EDIT:  Here are some of the date string functions I found by grepping the Wanderlust code:

```
(defun wl-make-date-string ()
  (let ((system-time-locale "C"))
    (format-time-string "%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")))

(defsubst wl-get-date-iso8601 (date)
  (or (get-text-property 0 'wl-date date)
      (let* ((d1 (timezone-fix-time date nil nil))
         (time (format "%04d%02d%02dT%02d%02d%02d"
               (aref d1 0) (aref d1 1) (aref d1 2)
               (aref d1 3) (aref d1 4) (aref d1 5))))
    (put-text-property 0 1 'wl-date time date)
    time)))

(defun wl-make-date-string ()
  (let ((s (current-time-string)))
    (string-match "\\`\\([A-Z][a-z][a-z]\\) +[A-Z][a-z][a-z] +[0-9][0-9]? *[0-9][0-9]?:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] *[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9][0-9]"
          s)
    (concat (wl-match-string 1 s) ", "
        (timezone-make-date-arpa-standard s (current-time-zone)))))

(defun wl-date-iso8601 (date)
  "Convert the DATE to YYMMDDTHHMMSS."
  (condition-case ()
      (wl-get-date-iso8601 date)
    (error "")))
```

Comment: So to make matters short, you want `23 Oct 2013` => `10_23_2013`?

Comment: If possible, I could also use some help (please) with the `re-search-forward` to extract the date `23 Oct 2013` (which could be any of 365 possibilities) and then convert it to `10_23_2013`.

Comment: If the input string has a very fixed format, like `Date:  Wed, 23 Oct 2013 12:18:15 -0700`, then
it's possible. Otherwise you need some kind of anchor to locate the date. Like the way org-mode does it.
I can write a function, that maps `Date:  Wed, 23 Oct 2013 12:18:15 -0700` => `10_23_2013`.
Is that enough?

Comment: I'm going to take a minute to grep the code of Wanderlust to locate the the date string that gets printed when displaying the buffer of an e-mail, and I'll post the code I find (which may be helpful to see the possibilities that will be generated).

Comment: I think this is it:  `(defun wl-make-date-string () (let ((system-time-locale "C")) (format-time-string "%a, %d %b %Y %T %z")))`  I have updated the question with a few functions relating to dates that I found by grepping the Wanderlust code.

Comment: FYI, when it's not for ad-hoc usage, it's better (and easy) to generate a more targeted regexp for matching thing. e.g.: `(defvar my-date-regexp
  (concat (regexp-opt '("Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Thu" "Fri" "Sat" "Sun"))
   ", [0-9]\\{1,2\\} "
   (regexp-opt '("Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"))
   " [0-9]\\{4\\}")
  "Matches dates of the form: %a, %d %b %Y (see \`format-time-string'.")`

Comment: Thank you, @phils, for the more targeted regexp.  In my own mind, I was contemplating 365 different possibilities and knew there had to be something more efficient.  I've learned a lot from @phils and @abo-abo on this this project.  I looked at the raw source of an existing e-mail on the server and saw that the date format (`"%a, %d %b %Y %T %z"`) already exists -- i.e., `Wanderlust` is merely displaying in the buffer the relevant portions of what is stored locally or on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the function. 
If you can find a way to extract `Wed, 23 Oct 2013 12:18:15 -0700`, it will produce
`10_23_2013.pdf`.

```
(defun transform-date (s &optional shift)
  (let ((time (apply 'encode-time
                     (org-read-date-analyze
                      s nil
                      (decode-time (current-time))))))
    (when shift
      (setq time (time-add time (days-to-time shift))))
    (format-time-string "%m_%d_%Y.pdf" time)))
```

Here's a simple finder for the date:

```
(defun find-and-transform ()
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (when (re-search-forward "Date: \\([^:]*?\\)[0-9]+:")
    (transform-date
     (match-string-no-properties 1))))
```